# is there a binary OR operator in python that works on arrays?

Tags: python, operators

I have come from a matlab background to python and i am just wondering if there is a simple operator in python that will perform the following function:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
c = a|b
print c
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

or would i have to write a separate function to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension. Use `izip` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) if you're using Python 2.

```
c = [x | y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Alternatively, [@georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) pointed out in a comment that you can import the *bitwise or* operator and use it with `map`. This is only slightly faster than the list comprehension. `map` doesn't need wrapped with `list()` in Python 2.

```
import operator
c = list(map(operator.or_, a, b))
```

### Performance

List comprehension:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]" \
> "[x | y for x, y in zip(a, b)]"

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 usec per loop
```

Map:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]; \
> from operator import or_" "list(map(or_, a, b))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 usec per loop
```

NumPy

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy; a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; \
> b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]" "na = numpy.array(a); nb = numpy.array(b); na | nb"

100000 loops, best of 3: 6.07 usec per loop
```

NumPy (where `a` and `b` have already been converted to numpy arrays):

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy; a = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]); \
> b = numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])" "a | b"

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 usec per loop
```

**Conclusion**: Unless you need NumPy for other operations, it's not worth the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

If your data was in numpy arrays then yes this would work:

```
In [42]:

a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
b = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
c = a|b
print(c)
[1 1 0 1 0 1]
Out[42]:
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: okay, thanks for that. so it won't work in standard arrays then?

Comment: Not for a list using your notation

Comment: Personally I think that numpy arrays are the most appropriate data structure if you're used to using arrays coming from a matlab background

Comment: i will probably end up using numpy arrays further down the track, but i think it is a bit overkill for my current application which is literally just combining two lists of decision variables

Answer (score 4):

`map(lambda (a,b): a|b,zip(a,b))`

Comment: Certainly the most pythonic way, I like the map approach :) Do you know if `map` yields better performance than using list comprehension ?

Comment: Well, a quick and not so accurate benchmark ! `python -m timeit 'a=[0,0,0,1,0]; b=[1,0,1,1,1]; c=map(lambda (a,b): a|b, zip(a,b))'` : best of 3: 1.01 usec per loop and `python -m timeit 'a=[0,0,0,1,0]; b=[1,0,1,1,1]; c=[x|y for x,y in zip(a,b)]'`: best of 3: 0.646 usec per loop :)

Comment: If you want `map`, it's just `map(operator.or_, a, b)` - no need for zip, map zips 'em for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*numpy.bitwise_or*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html#numpy.bitwise_or)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
>>> b = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> numpy.bitwise_or(a,b)
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = [q|w for q,w in zip(a,b)]
print c
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can work for multiple values since zip returns a tuple

```
bitlist = [x & y & z for x, y, z in zip(bitlist, green_mask_h, green_mask_s)]
```